# How to define flow associate with autonomous ordinary differential equation on $\boldsymbol{x}\ne \boldsymbol{x}_0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, vector-fields

In [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_(mathematics)#Formal_definition) a flow on a set $X$ is defined as

> [image]

And then a flow associate with an autonomous systems of ordinary differential equations is defined as

> [image]

As my understand, in the second definition, the set $S = \{\boldsymbol{x}(t)| t \in \mathbb{R}\} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ play the role of $X$ in the first definition of a flow. And the flow associates with the autonomous systems of ordinary differential equations should be a mapping $\varphi :S \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow S$. But in the second definition, just determine $\varphi $ at $S \times \boldsymbol{x}_0$. How to define $\varphi (\boldsymbol{x},t)$
with $\boldsymbol{x} \ne \boldsymbol{x}_0$? And how to prove: $\varphi (\varphi (\boldsymbol{x}_0,t),s) = \varphi (\boldsymbol{x}_0,s+t)$?

Edit: As @Arthur point out, $S = \mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the flow to start from a different point, then you solve the differential equation with that other point as the initial point instead. Wherever you want your flow to start (i.e. whatever point you want to use as the first argument to $\varphi$), that's what you put as $\boldsymbol x_0$ when you solve the differential equation.

Note that this also makes all of $\Bbb R^n$ into the $X$ from the first definition, since any point of $\Bbb R^n$ is a valid initial point for the differential equation.

Comment: So, when flow start at different point, we have the differential equation with different boundary condition. And how to prove: $\varphi (\varphi (x,t),s) = \varphi (x,s+t)$? I put this question in my question.

Comment: @ydhhat Intuitively obvious: Start at $x$, and follow the vector field where it tells you to go for $s$ seconds, then from there follow where the vector field tells you to go for $t$ seconds. You end up the same place as if you had instead from $x$ followed where the vector field tells you to to go for $s+t$ seconds. I'll have a think about a slightly more formal proof.

Comment: Could you give a simple, concrete example in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (picture is welcome)? I still not figure out.

Comment: @ydhhat Consider a flowing river, then, to be more concrete (where the currents in any one place never change). Start at some point $x$ in the river, and follow the currents for $s$ seconds. Then from there, follow the currents for $t$ seconds. Alternately, start at $x$ and follow the currents for $s+t$ seconds. Is it not obvious that these two end up in the same place?

Comment: Nice illustration. I think the formal proof is: $\varphi (\varphi (\boldsymbol{x},t),s) = \varphi (\boldsymbol{x},t + s)$ due to the uniqueness of solution with initial condition.